# Trailing slash on Azure web site

Tags: xml, azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

Have a problem to URL requests ending with trailing slash on Azure web site:
https://www.host.com/path/index.htm - working
https://www.host.com/path/index.htm/ not working

I added folowing rule to system.webServer of web.config in the root folder:

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.htm$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.html$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*/[^.]*\.[\d\w]+$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
        </rule>
```

Doesn't solve the problem.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? can you add <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />  and check if it resolves your issue?

Comment: I am getting "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." after adding <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" /> as well.

Answer (score 0):

Asked Microsoft support for help...
Here is correct answer that worked for me:

```
       <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)/$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

Added to web.config in the folder itself. Not in root folder.